# P2 build simpleconfigurator/bundles.info includes extra bundles

Tags: p2, pde

I have a problem building my product with p2. My product consists of the single custom feature, which includes my plugins together with org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator. I don't use org.eclipse.rcp or any other eclipse features.

The problem is that when I build my product with PDE simpleconfigurator collects only required bundles (which I have dependencies on). But when I use p2 director then simpleconfigurator/bundles.info and resulting plugins folder includes several extra bundles, which I never included in the dependencies, like:

```
com.ibm.icu
org.eclipse.swt
org.eclipse.ui
org.eclipse.ui.workbench
org.eclipse.core.databinding
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
org.eclipse.core.databinding.property
```

I would like to know where those bundles coming from in p2 build, and how can I control which of them are collected in simpleconfigurator/bundles.info file.

Thank you. Ulyana

Comment: Can you pls explain how do you use the p2 director?

Comment: I have my own PDE build file, and I specify p2 properties.

Comment: theoretically: seems that org.eclipse.rcp is somehow included... maybe it's listed as a dependency feature in some other feature you use. can you show your config?

Comment: that was my first guess too, but I don't have org.eclipse.rcp included as part of any my features. I have only org.eclipse.core.runtime and org.eclipse.ui. My problem is why the PDE+p2 builds those bundles as part of the product and normal PDE build doesn't.

Comment: hard to say without seeing your build script/config

Comment: ok I figured how this is happening but I can't understand why. I created simple product with single feature with dependencies on org.eclipse.core.runtime and org.eclipse.ui. When you build the product with PDE it builds it without any additional dependencies, but with PDE+p2 it grabs all the bundles I mentioned before in my question.

Comment: It is easy to test by exporting product with standard export wizard in Eclipse, by selecting Generate metadata (for p2 product) and de-selecting it for non-p2 product. It includes different number of plugins in a resulting product and I really wonder why?

Comment: it is not specific to my product at all, the simplest example as I described above produces the same result.